# How to draw lines in Android Edit Text?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am trying to build a notepad application. I want to have lines in the Edit Text view of my application which is a multi line Edit Text. Please let me know how to do this. Thank you for your time and advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this out.[notepad](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are best of just showing a background, not 'drawing lines'. Use the default background a View has:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)

Answer (score 0):

Since the size of the notepad will vary based upon the size of the phone's screen, a good option would be to create a canvas with a specified size and draw a line horizontally down the canvas in a constant interval. Then convert the canvas to a drawable and set the backgrounddrawable of the editText to the drawable.

Answer (score 0):

u can have this code in yr `xml` folder in `res`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF000000"
            />
            <padding android:bottom="20dip" />
</shape>
```

and include it in `setBackgroundResource()`