# EditText back padding

Tags: android, android-edittext, padding

This code helps me to draw text in EditText element.

```
public class LimitedEditText extends EditText
{

    private Paint limit_text_paint;

    /**
     * Current size of text displayed in the EditView.
     */
    private int current_text_size;
    /**
     * Maximum text size allowed.
     */
    private int maximum_text_size;
    /**
     * Default limit indicator X margin used.
     */
    private final int DEFAULT_X_MARGIN= 10;
    /**
     * Default limit indicator Y margin used.
     */
    private final int DEFAULT_Y_MARGIN= 20;
    /**
     * Flag indicating text size limit is unlimited.
     */
    public static final int UNLIMITED= -100;

    /**
     * LimitedEditText constructor.
     * @param context Context that will display this view.
     * @param attrs Set of attributes defined for this view.
     * @param defStyle Style defined for this view.
     */
    public LimitedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initComponents(attrs);
    }
    /**
     * LimitedEditText constructor.
     * @param context Context that will display this view.
     * @param attrs Set of attributes defined for this view.
     */
    public LimitedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        initComponents(attrs);
    }
    /**
     * LimitedEditText constructor.
     * @param context Context that will display this view.
     */
    public LimitedEditText(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        initComponents(null);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the UI components.
     * @param attrs Set of attributes defined for this view.
     */
    private void initComponents(AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        limit_text_paint= new Paint();
        limit_text_paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        limit_text_paint.setTextSize(20);
        maximum_text_size= UNLIMITED;
        current_text_size= 0;
        if(attrs!=null) //android:maxLength 
            maximum_text_size= attrs.getAttributeIntValue("android", "maxLength", UNLIMITED);

        super.addTextChangedListener(new  TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
            {
                if(maximum_text_size != UNLIMITED)
                    current_text_size= getText().toString().length();
                invalidate();
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {}
        });
    }

    /**
     * Set maximum text size for given EditText.
     * @param max Maximum number of characters allowed.
     */
    public void setMaxTextSize(int max)
    {
        maximum_text_size= max;
        if(max== UNLIMITED)
            setFilters(null);
        else
            setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(max)});
    }
    /**
     * Remove text size limit. 
     * This will stop drawing the amount of characters left.
     */
    public void removeTextSizeLimit()
    {
        setMaxTextSize(UNLIMITED);
    }
    /**
     * Get the X position of limit indicator.
     * @param text Text to be drawn on the limit indicator.
     * @return X position of limit indicator.
     */
    protected float getLimitIndicatorX(String text)
    {
        float widths[]= new float1;
        limit_text_paint.getTextWidths(text, widths);

        float sum= 0;
        for(float w: widths)
            sum+= w;
        return getWidth() + getScrollX() - sum - DEFAULT_X_MARGIN;
    }
    /**
     * Get the Y position of limit indicator.
     * @param text Text to be drawn on the limit indicator.
     * @return Y position of limit indicator.
     */
    protected float getLimitIndicatorY(String text)
    {
        return DEFAULT_Y_MARGIN + getScrollY();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(maximum_text_size== UNLIMITED)
            return;

        String text= current_text_size+"/"+maximum_text_size;
        canvas.drawText(text, getLimitIndicatorX(text), getLimitIndicatorY(text), limit_text_paint);
    }

}
```

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgX9E.png)

I need to draw it under the text(and blue line), but i can't do it , because after blue line is end of edittext. How could i do it? Of course, i can draw line  myself, but i think it will be not correct solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw lines in Android Edit Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760124/how-to-draw-lines-in-android-edit-text)

Comment: Yes , it possible, but not good solution